# IpTables / local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, iptables

I have some problem with my iptables rules. In my local host running MySQL server - on 3306 port.

I wrote some rules:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m tcp -j ACCEPT
```

But

```
IP OUTPUT drop: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3306 DPT=38124 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

And my chains

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:57261 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:2049 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 tcp
ACCEPT     udp  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  xx.xxx.xxx.xx        0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53 state ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 12/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IP INPUT drop: "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:57261 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            xx.xxx.xxx.xx        tcp dpt:2049 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            xx.xxx.xxx.xx        tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:3306 tcp
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            xx.xxx.xxx.xx        udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            xx.xxx.xxx.xx        tcp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 12/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "IP OUTPUT drop: "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Why `-m tcp`? Look at the log-line, It has DPT/dport that isn't 3306 like in your rules

Comment: Welcome! I think  the most common mistake for novice firewall administrators is that they add a new rule and then discover that it won't take effect. The reason for that is that the `-A` option **appends** that new rule, **after all existing rules** . The thing to remember is that firewall rules are checked in the order they are listed. The kernel will stop processing the chain when a rule is triggered that will either allow or dis-allow a packet or connection. So please post your complete firewall (with `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n` ) to see if any previous entries explain your observations.

Comment: @ptman You are right, but look .. OUTPUT rule. In log line I see blocked traffic via OUTPUT chain, where I set correct - soruce port, not destination.

Answer (score 2):

The **OUTPUT** rule does not work because the destination port on the client machine is random

To proper address the issue you could insert rules like below :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m tcp -j ACCEPT
```

AND

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m tcp -j ACCEPT
```

OR

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You can either allow it by specifying a **--sport**  (source port) or by allowing **RELATED** and **ESTABLISHED** traffic, provided you have a working conntrack module (which by default should be loaded)

Comment: "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m tcp -j ACCEPT"

Doesn't work too... I try this rule few days ago.

Comment: Post the output of `iptables-save` or if you don't have this command `iptables -nL`, maybe there is another rule thats preventing it.

Comment: You really should use the RELATED,ESTABLISHED rules, it simply makes things more manageable and has no drawbacks.

Comment: @bocian85, forgive me the long answer time. I posted my all iptables rules.